# formate custom cell output from horizontal to vertical cells

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following table setup:

| Date | Time | Name1 | Name2 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.0001 | 15 | Bob | Emily | ... |
| 02.02.0002 | 21 | Bob2 |  |  |

and I want to transform this into this:

| Date | Time | Names |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.0001 | 15 | Bob |
|  |  | Emily |
|  |  | ... |
| 02.02.0002 | 21 | Bob2 |
| 03.03.0003 | ... |  |

Without using any custom google script functions.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

One way to "reverse deduplicate" data is to use an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276), like this:

```
=query( 
  { 
    A1:B, C1:C; 
    A2:B, D2:D; 
    A2:B, E2:E 
  }, 
  "where Col1 is not null", 
  1 
)
```

The output will not match your expected result exactly, but the resulting table will be much easier to process to reports using `query()` or `filter()`.

If you have many columns to re-deduplicate, you may want to try the [Array Expression Formula Builder](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XlAbMfEhjQ1EFkGU0DH8nDFD9QV_Je48-Oz7JHuJyrI/edit?usp=sharing) spreadsheet.